# GLSL correspondence of dot( sina, 1..xxxx ) in CG

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, cg

Hi I am trying to convert a CG shader into GLSL shader. It is quite similar but I couldn't find the correspondence for

```
dot( sina, 1..xxxx );
```

Could you explain what this line does and help me to write GLSL equivalent.

Comment: Well, could you explain what it does? Is `sina` a variable or a constant or what? Which version of GLSL are you trying to convert it into? What is `1..xxxx` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @NicolBolas: looks like Cg allows swizzling on scalar values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `sina` is a 4 component vector what the snippet does is returning the sum of `sina`s components. The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is defined as follows:

[image]

The `.xxxx` part of the snippet you posted is a [swizzle](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/Cg_language.html#New_Vector_Operators) expanding the scalar before it (`1.` in your case) to a four component vector, evaluated that leads to:

```
dot(sina,1..xxxx) = sina.x * 1 + sina.y * 1 + sina.z * 1 + sina.w * 1
                  = sina.x + sina.y + sina.z + sina.w
```

As [GLSL does not allow swizzling](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) scalar values the GLSL equivalent would be:

```
dot(sina,vec4(1.));
```